# Spring MVC Restful 406 Not Acceptable Error

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, curl

I know this question has been asked before, and I've checked every message of Spring MVC with the 406 error message and I am beside myself not knowing how to fix this problem since I've tried just about everything put fourth by these previous answers.

This one web-service takes an email address, and returns back a user object in JSON.   I can tell you the unit test works great.  And I know we pass the Spring Security, we are executing the servlet ... the only problem now is the JSON output ... I don't get that, I get this error message.

So, to be exact:
Spring Core: 4.2.4.RELEASE
Spring Security: 4.0.3.RELEASE
Jackson Faster XML: 2.6.5 (core, databind, annotations)
                    2.7.0 doesn't seem to work yet ...

Here is the springmvc-servlet.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.agmednet.server.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
          <property name="objectMapper">
             <bean class="com.agmednet.server.HibernateAwareObjectMapper">

                     <property name="dateFormat">
                        <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"></constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                     </property>

             </bean>
          </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Here is the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserAccountController
{
@Autowired
private UserAccountService userAccountService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/email/{email:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody UserAccountEntity getByEmailAddress(@PathVariable("email") String email)
{
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    User user = null;
    if (principal instanceof User)
    {
        user = ((User) principal)
    }
    UserAccountEntity userAccount = userAccountService.getByEmailAddress(email);
    return userAccount;
}
}
```

As you can see, I have the Accept header setup, I have the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

I have a `SimpleCORSFilter` Code on top of this:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter
{
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept, If-Modified-Since, openam_token");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig){}
    public void destroy(){}
}
```

As you can see, this accepts my custom header for an "openam_token", but is has
"Accept" and "Content-Type" as well.

I am calling this from a linux box behind a firewall, so I have to SSH into the machine, and execute this curl statement:

```
curl -v -i -X GET -H "openam_token: AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcxfw-GSBSndg-4DMEyrEqcBgiTE4b4e3aE.*AAJTSQACMDE.*" -H "Content-Type: application/json, text/html" -H "Accept: application/json, text/html" backend.spring.mycompany.net:8080/services/api/users/email/user4252002@mycompany.com
```

So, here is what I am sending via curl in the request:

```
*   Trying 10.0.4.107...
* Connected to backend.spring.agmednet.net (10.0.4.107) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /services/api/users/email/user4252002@agmednet.com HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: backend.spring.agmednet.net:8080
> openam_token: AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcxfw-GSBSndg-4DMEyrEqcBgiTE4b4e3aE.*AAJTSQACMDE.*
> Content-Type: application/json, text/html
> Accept: application/json, text/html
```

And here is the response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept, If-Modified-Since, openam_token
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept, If-Modified-Since, openam_token
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
Expires: 0
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=76C4B28DD0B5D88EB9341944BDBCD045; Path=/services/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=76C4B28DD0B5D88EB9341944BDBCD045; Path=/services/; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 1110
Content-Length: 1110
< Date: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 14:30:28 GMT
Date: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 14:30:28 GMT


  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html><head>
  <title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.30 - Error report</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>HTTP Status 406 - </h1>
  <div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p>
  <p><b>message</b> <u></u></p>
  <p><b>description</b> 
  <u>The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating 
  responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request*  
  Connection #0 to host backend.spring.agmednet.net left intact
  "accept" headers.</u></p>
  <hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.30</h3></body></html>
```

Ultimately, this is the error message listed above:

```
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request* Connection #0 to host backend.spring.mycompany.net left intact
```

"accept" headers.

So, I am using `@ResponseBody`, I am using the latest Jackson 2.x version.  I am following all the suggestions from previous questions and I still can't get this to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For starters remove `@EnableWebMvc` you already  have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` which does the same.

Comment: Remove EnableWebMVC as stated above, and why do you want to receive a legible email-address as path-variable.. Recieve a simple string and check if it's a valid email. Secondly, you don't need to explicitly add produces and accepts.

Comment: First of all ....  the web-service is not checking for the validity of an email.  This is based on a need we have, we pass in an email, and we do a database lookup on that field and return a user from it, that is a business need!!!!   Secondly, I understand a I don't need a "produces" but it doesn't hurt to have the "accept" but I will remove it and see if it fixes my problem.  The only reason I added them was to test out and see if that fixes the issue, it didn't. And as previously stated, I have already removed @EnableWebMvc from my controllers.   So, I am in the process of testing now.

Comment: removed the produces and accept from the controller, and removed the @EnabledWebMvc annotation ... and still no success.  Why am I not surprised?!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @EnableWebMVC wasn't the problem, and everything you see in the question is 100% correct.  I have two other web-services that worked fine.  The problem ultimately was with the curl statement itself:

```
curl -v -i -X GET -H /
"openam_token: AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcxfw-GSBSndg-4DMEyrEqcBgiTE4b4e3aE.*AAJTSQACMDE.*" /
-H "Content-Type: application/json, text/html" /
-H "Accept: application/json, text/html"  /
backend.spring.mycompany.net:8080/services/api/users/email/user4252002@mycompany.com
```

If you notice, the URL and the path variable is not in quotes.
if you notice, the email address has an @ symbol in it, which I found out means something to curl.  So, what I did was change my curl to the following.

```
curl -v -i -X GET -H /
"openam_token: AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcxfw-GSBSndg-4DMEyrEqcBgiTE4b4e3aE.*AAJTSQACMDE.*" /
-H "Content-Type: */*" /
-H "Accept: */*" /    
"backend.spring.mycompany.net:8080/services/api/users/email/user4252002%40mycompany%2Ecom"
```

1) I encoded the email address myself @ to %40 and period-dot to %2E
You can use whatever tool you meant to encode the path variable.

2) Even though I am returning a java object transformed into JSON, I changed headers "Accept" and "Content-Type" to "*/*".

That was it.  This worked and the 406 error message went away.